# iOS connecting to mysql database does not display new rows

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c

I have this code and it retrieves the name of the users from MySQL database. However, it does not load the new entries that I just put into the database.

```
-(void) fetchUsers {
    @try
    {
        NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://malaebna.com/usersMalaebna.php"];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        NSMutableArray *jsonArray2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        preCalcArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.count; i++) {
            NSString *mEmail = [[jsonArray2 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"email"];
            NSString *mPass = [[jsonArray2 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"password"];
            NSString *mNumber = [[jsonArray2 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"number"];
            NSString *mReservations = [[jsonArray2 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"reservations"];

            NSLog(mEmail);
            NSLog(mPass);

            [preCalcArray addObject:[[users alloc] initWithEmail:mEmail andPassword:mPass andNumber:mNumber andReservations:mReservations]];

            //[self.tableView reloadData];
        }

    }
    @catch (NSException *ex) {
    }
}
```

For example, I have a create account page and I will create an account exampleemail@gmail.com.

And it will successfully insert into the database.

[image]

However when I go back to the login page and fetch the users, the new entry is not fetched.

[image]

I would have to wait or refresh the PHP page on my chrome browser for it to appear in the application.

This is my php fetch script:

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli("localhost","","","");
 $con ->set_charset("utf8");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}


// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I desperately need help with this.

Comment: `$temparray` is pointless. `$row` is already an array, and all you're doing is doing a redundant copy. `$resultArray[] = $row` is ALL you need to store that row.

Comment: i just tried it, still does not load new entries unless i refresh

Comment: Please, whenever possible post plain text as text and not as an image. It makes it a lot harder to re-use in any potential solution.

Comment: Sorry i'm new here, will be noted, thanks.